# Navigation Viewcontroller not showing back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Here let me mention viewcontroller as vc.. Using navigation controller I'm moving from vc1 to vc2. and from vc2 to vc3 I'm moving programatically, using modal. And I'm returning back again programatically to vc2. But here my navigation bar back button is disappeared in vc2 and I'm not able to move back from vc2 to vc1. Navigation bar back button works before entering vc3, I mean I can move to and from between vc1 to vc2 as many times as I can, but if I once enter vc3... I can come back to vc2 and from there I cannot go back to vc1.

vc2 to vc3....

```
VC3 *vc3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC3"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
```

vc3 to vc2.....

```
VC2 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "vc3 to vc2" you need to come as dismissing view controller `vc3`.Replace your code of vc3 to vc2.....

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In your code you are again presenting vc2 on vc3 instead of dismissing `v3`.